# Exponential and Uniform distribution with conditional probability

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, conditional-probability

A computer lab has two printers. Printer I handles 40% of all the jobs. its printing time is Exponential with the mean of 2 minutes. Printer II handles the remaining 60% of jobs. Its printing time is Uniform between 0 minutes and 5 minutes. A job is printed in less than 1 minute. What is the probability that it was printed by printer I?

My attempt to solve this looks like the following (sorry, first attempt at LaTeX):

Given:

$P(Printer 1) = .4$

$P(Printer 2) = .6$

For Printer 1, $1/\lambda$ = 2 minutes.  Therefore $\lambda = 1/2$.

$P(time < 1 minute | Printer 1) = F(1) = 1 - e^{-1/2} = 0.3935$

With printer 2, the std. dev. given is 5 minutes. 1 minute is .2 standard deviations from the mean of 0.

$P(time < 1 minute | Printer 2) = \Phi(0.2) = 0.5793$

By Bayes rule and the law of total probability,
$P(Printer 1 | time < 1 minute) =$

$P(Printer 1) * P(time < 1 minute | Printer 1)\over P(Printer 1) * P(time < 1 minute | Printer 1) + P(Printer 2) * P(time < 1 minute | Printer 2)$

$=$

$0.4 * 0.3935
\over
(0.4 * 0.3935+ 0.6 * 0.5793)$

$=$

$0.3117$

Only, the answer given is .567.  I can't tell where I've gone wrong.  Any hints (or even tips on better use of LaTeX) would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the normal doing butting in?

Comment: I was under the impression $\Phi(x)$ corresponded to $P(X < x)$ for a normal uniform distribution.  Normalizing the distribution from [0, 5] to [0, 1] gave me 0.2 as an argument to $\Phi(x)$ , but evidently that is wrong.  Looking at your answer below, I still can't tell why.

Comment: The time on printer 2 is uniform on $[0,5]$, so the probability it is $\le `1$ is $\frac{1}{5}$.

Comment: I guess my question ultimately boils down to 'Why does $\Phi(x)$ not work here, if it means P(X < x) with standard normal variables (over the interval [0,1])?'  I standardized the 5 to become $1 \over 5$  $= .2$, but that is evidently unrelated--why?

Comment: The normal distribution is nowhere mentioned, and the two rancom variable types used (exponential and uniform) are far from normal. It is a Bayes's Formula/Conditional probability calculation. I suggest you do the calculation, using the number $0.2$ of the answer instead of the $\Phi$ stuff. If you cannot get it, I will write a fully detailed solution tomorrow. But the solution only uses stuff you know, so I expect there will be no need.

Comment: I think I just confused "standard normal" with "uniform" for... reasons unknown.  It's all clearer now, thanks.  No idea where I came up with that.  Answer accepted, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability the time is less than $1$, given it is printer $2$, is $\frac{1}{5}$.